# Please help with naming the label on Feynman diagram

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman, feynman

I want to get this Feynman diagram:
[image]

I have following code, however when I add  `\(g(b,\overline a)\)` , I get many errors. Could you please tell me how should I get desired result?

```
\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
    i1[particle=\(u(r)\)] -- [anti fermion] a -- [anti fermion] i2[particle=\(u(b)\)],
    a -- [gluon, edge label= \(g\)] b,
};
\end{center}
```

Comment: @campa Awesome, it worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was exactly answering this. @somerandomguest also please make your MWE compilable right away (I had to guess that you used `tikz-feynman` from your other question, I’ve never used that before), the `standalone` class is quite nice for this. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to parsing issue with the comma, you have to use braces {}:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
    i1[particle=\(u(r)\)] -- [anti fermion] a -- [anti fermion] i2[particle=\(u(b)\)],
    a -- [gluon, edge label= {\(g,\overline a\)}] b,
};

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image: feynman]